# Use Django Action to Populate Database: Show Drop Down Action Menu Even for Empty DB

Tags: django

Using django, I have a startup script that loads static data into the database.
Currently I call it via a url, but thought it be nice if it be done from within the admin menu of the respective table.

I found the option to use admin actions for this, but allas, they do not show up if the database is empty. Any idea how to still show the admin actions dropdown menu?